# Why am I constantly getting object errors?

Tags: asp-classic

I have cut and paste this example from http://devguru.org/Technologies/xmldom/quickref/node_selectSingleNode.html

and I can't get it to work.

I keep getting object errors like this:

Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01A8)
Object required

This is the code and xml file I am using

```
    <%
    option explicit

    Dim objXMLDoc

    Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objXMLDoc.async = False
    objXMLDoc.load(Server.MapPath("vocabulary.xml"))

    Dim Node

Set Node = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("label")
Response.write Node.text

%>
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <labels>
        <label>Some label</label>
    </labels>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error mentioned is probably at the level of the last line.  Assuming all other calls to the XMLDOM object worked smoothly, **selectSingleNode would return null**, since "label" as a path would not be found.

Try with

```
Set Node = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("labels/label")
```

instead.  Alternatively, and this is a good practice with this type of DOM logic, you could test for successful return from selectSingleNode

```
Set Node = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("label")
If Node = Nothing
Ehen
   Response.Write  "Not found..."
Else
Response.Write Node.text
```

Comment: "labels" is the document element, so documentElement.selectSingleNode call should indeed return the one label node.

Comment: I needed to use a full path with selectSingleNode for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried your codes and it works. So there are 2 possible reasons that I can think of.

1. The error is thrown from `objXMLDoc.load` and not `objXMLDoc.selectSingleNode` which means the XML file is not found (or permission is denied?). Check that the file path is indeed valid and can be accessed. Try `Response.write objXMLDoc.text` to see if you can get anything, it should display "Some label" too.
2. I'm just guessing but it could due to a different version of the "MSXML" library

If it's not reason 1, you might want to try the following code (from [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757846%28VS.85%29.aspx)):

```
objXMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath" 'add this line
Dim Node
Set Node = objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("//label") 'use //label
Response.write Node.text
```

Comment: I also tried switching msxml versions. I'm not sure if that helped or not.